# validar select input si el value es vacio o null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Saludos por favor quiero validar el select si no se selecciona una opcion del value que se requerido, nesecito validar el select. Gracias

```js
import React from "react";
let users = [
  { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
  { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" }
];

users.unshift({
  value: "",
  label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]"
});
const handleInputChange = () => (e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  localStorage.setItem("item_id", `${val}`);
};
const General = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="form-select"
        name="options"
        onChange={handleInputChange()}
      >
        {users.map((item) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
export default General;
```

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende bien tu pregunta. Si quieres validar un select simplemente pregunta si su valor es nulo. Dependiendo si es nulo o si no lo es, haces lo que quieras en tu app. Puedes hacerlo así:

```
if(!val)
    console.log('No ha seleccionado ninguna opción')
  else
    console.log(`El valor seleccionado es ${val}`)
```

Donde `val` es el valor actual del select. Te adjunto un ejemplo reutilizando tu código.

```js
let users = [
  { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
  { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" }
];

users.unshift({
  value: "",
  label: "[Seleccione una opción]"
});
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  if(!val)
    console.log('No ha seleccionado ninguna opción')
  else
    console.log(`El valor seleccionado es ${val}`)
};
const General = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="form-select"
        name="options"
        onChange={handleInputChange}>
        {users.map((item) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<General />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```